# Umbrella term for word types

Tags: terminology, syntactic-analysis, semantics, technical

So, when we analyze language (spoken or written), we tend to classify words according to their syntactic roles or functions (right?): ***nouns***, **pronouns**, **verbs**, **adverbs**, **adjectives**, **conjunctions**, and so on.
But what do we call that superset that contains all these subtypes?
I can't think what else to call them; so I've just been referring to them as *types*, *word types*, etc. But that seems way too ambiguous.
I feel like there's a technical term, or something more specific that I should know; on the tip of my tongue, but I'm drawing a blank.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for the term **parts of speech**:

> There are eight parts of speech in the English language: noun, pronoun, verb, adjective, adverb, preposition, conjunction, and interjection.
>   <sub>[The Eight Parts of Speech - TIP Sheets - Butte College](http://www.butte.edu/departments/cas/tipsheets/grammar/parts_of_speech.html)</sub>

Comment: Actually, no. This is **not** an accurate list of the English parts of speech. There are more types than eight; in English, for instance, there are articles and complementizers, among other. The actual name for the actual list is _word class, lexical class_, or _lexical category_.

Comment: This particular list is the [original Latin list of 8 parts](http://www.thelatinlibrary.com/don.html) (_nomen, pronomen, uerbum, aduerbium, participium, coniunctio, praepositio, interiectio_), with _Participle_ thrown out and _Adjective_ put in its place (Roman grammarians didn't believe in adjectives; they called them nouns).

Comment: That's.. not what I was looking for.